# angular injector with asp.net Boilerplate

Tags: angularjs, boilerplate

In http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dynamic-Web-API..  How does string 'abp.services.tasksystem.task' get resolved?

I know the $injector resolve the string..   but how can we come up with string 'abp.services.tasksystem.task' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the auto-generated proxy services in angularjs, you have to include this file:

```
<script src="~/api/AbpServiceProxies/GetAll?type=angular"></script>
```

It will register all the proxy services as angular's services into an abp module.

The content of the file might look like this:

```
angular.module('abp').service('abp.services.tasksystem.task', function () {
  // the proxy implementation
});
```

That why you will be able to inject the `abp.services.tasksystem.task` service in your app.

PS. Note that those `.` dot-notation are just a service name, not a real namespace thing.